# UIWebView does not render correctly

Tags: ios, xcode, uiwebview, webkit

I have `UIWebView` on top of my `UIViewController`. Loaded content is paged via CSS columns. Button on top just sets `contentOffset` of `UIWebView`'s `scrollView`. After some scrolling forward, `UIWebView` does not renders content, but inside Debug View Hierarchy renders correctly. The same issues on device (iOS 9.3) too. Any ideas how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was because I tried to hide/show UIWebView on page change